# Giving names to returned values with python type hints

Tags: python, type-hinting

Let's say I have a function like

```
def basic_stats(data: List[float]):
    """This returns a tuple with the mean and median values of the data
    """
    return (np.mean(data), np.median(data))
```

and I want to use type hints to self-document the code instead of a comment.  The standard way isn't super clear:

```
def basic_stats(data: List[float]) -> Tuple[float, float]:
```

because you can't tell by looking at the hint which output float is which.

Sometimes I've seen people do this:

```
def basic_stats(data: List[float]) -> Tuple["mean", "median"]:
```

which compiles just fine, and actually gives the humans what they need, but doesn't help the IDEs or `mypy`s.  (Although I'm yet to see those actually be useful in the real world yet, but that's maybe a different story.)

Is there any way to do both which is valid, pythonic, and useful?    I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
def basic_stats(data: List[float]) -> Tuple[mean:float, median:float]:
```

or should we just stick with something like

```
def basic_stats(data: List[float]) -> Tuple["mean:float", "median:float"]:
```

Or anything coming in a proposed PEP to solve this?

Comment: You've yet to see static type checking be useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I normally do this—assigning new names to float—may not be to everyone's liking, but mypy accepts it and it makes the code completion so much more helpefull. It can also reduce errors, such as when computing a tuple `(shape: float, scale: float)` or similar where mixing the return value up would be really bad, but not a "code error" as such since they are both floats.

Here's what I would have done with your code:

```
from typing import List, Tuple


mean = float
median = float


def basic_stats(data: List[float]) -> Tuple[mean, median]:
    """
    Compute the mean and median of a list of numbers
    """
    N = len(data)
    assert N > 0
    mean: float = sum(data) / N
    median: float = sorted(data)[N//2]
    return mean, median
    
    
print(basic_stats([1.0, 1.0, 1.0]))
print(basic_stats([3.0, 1.0, 2.0]))
```

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing that can do that in the type hints. I can think of several reasons not to, such as overwriting a variable in the caller with the same name you're returning.

An approach might be to return a named tuple using `namedtuple` from `collections` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) or a `NamedTuple` from the `typing` module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple)

Comment: Good idea!  So would `-> namedtuple('stat's, ['mean, median']):` do what I want?  Unfortunately `-> typing.NamedTuple['mean, median']:` doesn't run, which would be pythonic.

Comment: You should read the documentation. That's not how either of them work. :-)

Comment: :/ typos aside, I believe `namedtuple('stats', ['mean', 'median'])` is the correct way to define the named tuple I want. I'm not sure if that works at all in a type hint - which is basically my question, and would be nice.  Because explicitly defining a new class which is really heavy weight for code readability.

For `typing.NamedTuple` obviously that's not how it works, because it doesn't run as of py3.10.  But I'm pointing out this would be a nearly ideal solution to my Q if it worked.

Also, RTFM isn't a great answer on SO.

Comment: You would first declare the named tuple and that would give it a name, then use the name as the type in the hint.